# UIKit/UIKit.h not found on Facebook Notification SDK (FBNotification)

Tags: ios, facebook, objective-c, push-notification

Im trying compile my project, but after a long time without open it, i started get an error about FBNotification SDK.

The message is:

> In file included from /Users/paulo/Developer/workspaces/xcode/xyz-ios-swift/Pods/FBNotifications/iOS/FBNotifications/FBNotifications/Internal/Models/Components/FBNAnimatedImage.m:19:
>
> /Users/paulo/Developer/workspaces/xcode/xyz-ios-swift/Pods/FBNotifications/iOS/FBNotifications/FBNotifications/Internal/Models/Components/FBNAnimatedImage.h:19:9:
>   fatal error: 'UIKIt/UIKit.h' file not found
>
> import UIKIt/UIKit.h
>   ---------^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   1 error generated.

Can anyone help me with it?

Thanks.

Comment: Este é o StackOverflow em Português. Traduza a sua pergunta para português